# Adhesion of Super Glue (containing ethyl cyanoacrylate) and PVDF (polyvinylidene fluoride) film

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials, plastic, building-design, adhesive

Would it be considered safe to use super glue, which contains ethyl cyanoacrylate, to attach a PVDF film to a metal alloy?

It says super glue is not recommended for polyethylene or polypropylene. However, I am not sure about the hazards for polyvinylidene fluoride.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not one of safety; it is just that PE, PP and PVDF are almost impossible to get anything to stick to, including glue. It is doubtful that crazy glue would work on it. you can try latex-based glue, this is what's used in stickytape. There are industrial-strength versions which fall under the category of pressure-sensitive adhesives. 3M makes these.

Comment: Oh I see. Are there any effective methods to directly attach PVDF to steel or any other metal alloy?

Comment: you can try latex-based glue, this is what's used in stickytape. There are industrial-strength versions which fall under the category of *pressure-sensitive adhesives*.

Comment: Double-Coated PET Film Tape

Comment: Actual answers vs answering in comments is best.